# List<String> ----> to int [ ] [ ] arr

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, int

Well I have been stumped as to the best way to do this, I have written the code to read in lines of code from txt files as List.  I can then print specific parts or convert this to an array of objects.  But, ultimately I would like to have just a 2d int array you can see often in C/C++.  I am very green when it comes to java, having only started earlier this week.  I have like it up until this point of making dynamic 2d arrays at run time.  Can any of you suggest a good way to get to a 2d int array from where i am currently stuck.  I was just about to convert it to a char array using 'toChar', then to take the (value@index-48) and store it in its corresponding spot, but that seems pretty ghetto to me.

====updated==========================

eh, thanks for all the replies, but I just figured out how to do it using doubles, so for anyone else, here you go.  I would still rather have int, since I have already built my other matrixops classes using this type, but Double shouldn't be an issue i guess.

```
package uaa.cse215;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class ReadMatrix {
    private Double[][] A;
    private Double[][] B;
    private int count;

    public int filedir(String matrix) throws Exception{
        Double[][] Temp;
        String[] arr;
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(matrix));
        String s;
        List<String> textFile = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((s=rd.readLine())!=null) {
            textFile.add(s);
            }
        String splitarray[] = textFile.get(0).split(" ");//run once to grab # cols
        int rows = textFile.size();//number of rows
        int cols = splitarray.length;//number of cols
        Temp = new Double[rows][cols]; // now can initiate array
            for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
                s = textFile.get(i);
                arr = s.split(" ");
                for (int j=0; j<cols; j++) { 
                    Temp[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(arr[j]);
                }
            }
            count++;
            if (count == 1){
                A = Temp;
            }
            else
                B = Temp;


            rd.close();
            return(1);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the input matrix dimentions are dynamic or jagged you can use

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

to read numbers and than copy it to raw 2d array if you want.

java.util.Scanner has many handy methods for reading "typed" data from input

Here's an example reading file to 2D array

```
public static int[][] read2DArray(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner sc = null;

        List<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        int columnCount = 0;
        int[][] arr = null;

        try {

            sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

                // Read line
                String line = sc.nextLine();

                // Split it
                String[] nums = line.split(" ");

                if (nums.length > columnCount) {
                    columnCount = nums.length;
                }

                // Convert to integers and add to list
                list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
                for (String n : nums) {
                    list.get(list.size() - 1).add(new Integer(n));
                }
            }

            // Convert list to array
            int rowCount = list.size();
            arr = new int[rowCount][columnCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size(); j++) {
                    arr[i][j] = list.get(i).get(j);
                }
            }

        } finally {
            if (sc != null) {
                sc.close();
            }
        }

        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: Where were you with this 2 nites ago lol. I been looking all over for something like this, and with comments !!!  Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Please note that Java has the `char` data type which is a 16bit unsigned integer holding a UTF-16 code point. `int` is in Java always a signed 32 bit integer. So if you want a C like Arrays of chars representing the content of a String, you should use a `char[][]`

To convert the content of your `List<String>` into a 2d array you can use the following code:

```
char[][] twoDarray = new char[textFile.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < textFile.size(); i+)
{
     twoDarray[i] = textFile.get(i).toCharArray();
}
```

The array twoDarray then contains all Strings each as a char array.

Comment: I don't see a problem with spaces. If the original Strings contain spaces it is intended behaviour that the char[][] retains those, a space is merely a character with special use.

Comment: Nope, the PO wants to get the integers out straight away. Parsing a space character will result in a number format exception

Comment: GETah is correct, I wish to have a 2d array of integers as you would say in C/C++, thank you though for the info, since I didn't know about the int in java.  That would explain why it is being fussy when i try to use it.  What should I be labeling as the type if i just want integer values?

Answer (score 1):

This line won't compile

```
splitarray[j] = textFile.get(i).split(" ");
```

as `splitarray[j]` is of type `String` and `split` returns an array of `String`s

Do the following instead:

```
   for(int row=0;row<textFile.size();row++){
       String[] splitarray = textFile.get(row).split(" ");
       for(int col=0;col<splitarray.length;col++){
           tmp[row][col] = Integer.parse(splitarray[col]);
       }
   }
```

Comment: yeah i saw the error, i was going to try the parse method but i've only seen it done with object arrays so wasn't sure what to do there.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data file contains ascii-represented numbers that you want parsed into integers:

```
11 -9 13
12 55 102
1 1 1024
```

Then you can use the [`Integer(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer%28java.lang.String%29) constructor to parse your string objects.

Also, I suggest splitting each row only once. It won't matter much for small arrays, but the larger your inputs get, the more you'll needlessly recompute the splits.

An (untested) re-writing:

```java
int tmp[][] = new int [rows][cols]; 
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
    splitarray = textFile.get(i).split(" ");
    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
        tmp[i][j] = Integer(splitarray[j]);
    }
}
```